# How to build Kafka-like queue with NATS

Tags: go, queue, nats.io, nats-jetstream

I need to build a queue using NATS. I'm writing a Go service but it seems that it's more about NATS JetStreams configuration.

What I want to do:

1. a queue, that allows to connect with multiple consumers with the same group ID. NATS server to divide load between consumers within the group and rebalances it when consumers connect/disconnect. Delivery – exactly once in a group.
2. multiple groups can read same messages. So I can run two groups with different names and both will get the same set of messages.

I succeeded to create a service that meets requirement #1 (see below). I use NATS with JetStreams. NATS server splits messages between several instances with the same group ID. NATS server stores messages in case no consumer is connected.

The problem is that it doesn't fit #2 – if I run another instance with another group ID (`Durable` field in `ConsumerConfig`) I get an error:

```
nats: API error: code=400 err_code=10099 description=multiple non-filtered consumers not allowed on workqueue stream
```

So the question is – is it possible at all to implement with NATS what I need?

**Here's my consumer code.**

```golang
func consumeFromNats(ctx context.Context) error {
    nc, err := nats.Connect("localhost:4222")
    // handling error

    js, err := jetstream.New(nc)
    // handling error

    streamConfig := jetstream.StreamConfig{
        Name:      "TEST.STREAM",
        Retention: jetstream.WorkQueuePolicy,
        Subjects:  []string{"events"},
    }

    stream, err := js.CreateOrUpdateStream(ctx, streamConfig)
    // handling error

    consumer, err := stream.CreateOrUpdateConsumer(ctx, jetstream.ConsumerConfig{
        Durable: "consumer-group",
    })
    // handling error

    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        nc.Close()
    }()

    for {
        msg, err := consumer.Next()
        // handling error

    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: is the second requirement for auditing/reporting? to me your requirements are contradictory. afaik with workQueuePolicy the idea is to delete the message once it's consumed. if you want to read from multiple consumers how is the server going to know when to delete the message? having said that maybe you can mirror the stream? https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats_admin/jetstream_admin/replication

Comment: The second requirement is ok – imagine you have two services that process some events stream independently. Each has it's own purpose to read events and the way to process it. Some moment you may need to run several instances of each service to split the load. Here's the moment when you need to have several independent subscribers groups.

Answer (score 2):

As @mtmk mentioned, workqueue retention policy stream is one that deletes message after it has been processed by any consumer.

In NATS, each consumer is a "view" into the stream - it keeps track of the sequences and acks. Workqueue retention deletes messages from stream as soon as it has been acked. Because of that, you can't have multiple consumers with overlapping subjects on the same workqueue stream.

To get you behavior, you can create a `limits` based stream, or even `interest` stream (which will be closer to current behavior). Check the docs: https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/jetstream/streams#retentionpolicy

Then, you can create as many consumers as you need. Each consumer will get all messages.

To load balance the messages for one consumer, just bind more clients to it.

Each consumer will get all messages, messages will be load balanced across all clients that bound to it.

Comment: I found a way to implement what I need. It's necessary to create a stream with `LimitsPolicy`. Then you create a consumer with specific consumer-group-id that is set to `Durable` config field. In this case two consumers with the same consumer-group-id will behave as a group – only one instance will receive the message.

Comment: There's only one issue – how to guarantee that messages with the same attribute (some ID for example) passes to the same subscriber (to guarantee messages order).

Comment: Just specify that ID as part of the subject (like `events.id.data`) and then create consumers aware of those. For example: `events.15.>`.
Such consumer will get everything that is `events.15` and whatever comes after it (> is a forward wildcard).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case and used the following configuration  `jetstream.InterestPolicy` with `Durable Consumers`, each consumer can be subscribed by multiple processors (load balancing) and with different consumer name same messages can be consumer (different processing groups)